# Creating new tables on the fly using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is actually the first time I'm posting something here. The problem I have is driving me crazy since I know such functionality exists elsewhere.

I'm trying to find a way to create new tables on the fly on node js using sequelize without having to restart the database (a DB implemented with SQL).
Moreover, I also need to create new associations between those new table and existing ones.

Why do I need this:
I'm creating a crm and one of the functionalities I want to add is to let users create new types of objects that could have fields referencing to other preexisting ones.

And I can't just restart the whole database everytime a user is creating a new object or fields.
If you guys know how to achieve that or maybe advising me to build the database with another language I'll go for it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/markgardner/node-flywaydb creates a NodeJs-wrapper around Flyway, a migration tool.

Comment: @Natrium Nice but are you sure that way we won't need to restart the db before starting the migration?

Comment: We use Flyway (without Node) for migrations and we don't have to restart our database. It's just creating tables and adding columns, no need to restart.

Comment: If you want to use Sequelize only then you need to look at `QueryInterface` in the API.